# Checkbox resize in yii2

Tags: css, yii2

I use checkbox in my yii2 project. I want to resize it but don't know how to do that. Can I resize checkbox in yii2? How to do that?

This is my code:

```
$form->field($model, 'id')->checkbox(['label' => '&nbsp;&nbsp;Vote', 'size' => 'lg'])
```

Comment: That is not related to yii or php anyway, tag your question as css and bootstrap.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

create a **CSS** **class** and apply **properties** as you want

```
.custom{
  width: 30px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
}
```

Use class in your Yii code :

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'id')->checkbox(['label' => 'Vote', 'class' => 'custom']) ?>
```